# How to quickly backup and restore kubernetes cluster in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, backup, restore

Our product dependency on the Kubernetes cluster is growing steadily and it may well be the case that an accident might happen at any moment where the cluster/resource may be deleted by an administrator.

What is the easy way to **back up** the cluster in a way that it could be restored quickly if an unfortunate event occurs?

Currently, we maintain a batch script which backs up all the named resources. The CD pipelines are set from git repositories- so, recreating workloads is not the case.

We are worried about setting up namespaces, ingress, etc quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use Velero ⛵⛵ formerly known as Heptio Ark. I used that  in prod previously and worked pretty well.

- https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero